# Is there a destructor for a pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
string * str=new string;
delete str;
```

when I delete 'str' which points to an object, do two destructors get called - one for the pointer itself, and one for the object it points to?

What would the pointer's destructor do?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please try to write proper and full English sentences as much as possible, even if it isn't your native language (it isn't for me either) - the question just doesn't make any sense now.

Comment: I'm guessing that English isn't your first language, but I'm afraid it's really unclear what you are actually asking here. I'll edit your question to clarify what I think you mean (otherwise I think your question will get closed very quickly) but feel free to roll it back or change it if it doesn't match what you intended.

Answer (score 16):

`delete` just causes the object that the given pointer is pointing at to be destroyed (in this case, the `string` object. The pointer itself, denoted by `str`, has automatic storage duration and will be destroyed when it goes out of scope like any other local variable.

Note, however, that non-class types do not have destructors. So even when you use `delete` with non-class types, no destructor is called, but *when* the pointer goes out of scope, it gets destroyed as normally happens with any other *automatic* variable (means the pointer just reaches the end of its lifetime, though the memory pointed to by the pointer is not deallocated *until* you  use `delete` to explicitly deallocate it.).

Comment: The "destructor" for non-class types is commonly achieved by moving the stack pointer. This is also what happens for class type objects with automatic storage after the non-trivial stuff happens in its destructor.

Comment: @rubenvb Moving the stack pointer has nothing to do with destruction.  Storage for local variables is typically allocated and  freed by changing the stack pointer.  It is also typically done at start and end of the function, rather than when the standard actually requires it (under the "as if" rule).

Comment: @James I didn't mean to say anything of the sort. What I meant was what you are saying. But I'm quite sure that the *raw* memory (de)allocation for class types is also done by moving the stack pointer. In between the raw allocation and deallocation is where the constructor's and desctructor's non-trivial code is executed.

Comment: @rubenvb: lets not confuse the term "destructor" by *redefining* it. In C++, the term *destructor* has well-defined meaning already, especially when we talk about "types".

Comment: @rubenvb How memory allocation is done depends on the lifetime of the object, and is independent of the type, and whether there is a destructor or not.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of destructor is applicable only to objects (i.e. entities defined with `class` or `struct`), not to plain types, like a pointer is. A pointer lives just like a `int` variable does.

Comment: An "object" in C++ (in the strict sense of the word) is a region of memory. I think you mean class types instead.

Answer (score 4):

The pointer it self doesn't been destructed by the `delete` statement. but as any scope variable it's been destroyed when the scope ends.

Example:

```
void Function()
{
    string * str=new string;
    delete str; // <-- here the string is destructed
} // <-- here the pointer is "destructed", which is mean it's memory freed from the stuck but no actual destruction function is called..
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I delete 'str' which points to an object, do two destructors get called - one for the pointer itself, and one for the object it points to?

No. `delete` takes a pointer argument. It destroys the object that's pointed to (using its destructor, if it has one, and doing nothing otherwise), and deallocates the memory that's pointed to. You must previously have used `new` to allocate the memory and create the object there.

The pointer itself is not affected; but it no longer points to a valid object, so you mustn't do anything with it. This is sometimes known as a "dangling pointer".

> What would the pointer's destructor do?

Nothing. Only class types have destructors.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor for a raw pointer, like your example of `std::string*`, is trivial (just like the destructors for other primitive types: `int`, `double`, etc.)

Smart pointer classes have non-trivial destructors that do things like free resources, adjust reference counts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I like the simplification you get from the notion that every type has a destructor. That way you don't have a mental glitch with a template that explicitly destroys a stored value, even if the type of that stored value is an `int` or a pointer:

```
template <class T> struct wrapper {
    unsigned char data[sizeof(T)];
    wrapper(T t) { ptr = new (data) T; }
    ~wrapper() { (T*)&data->~T(); } // ignore possible alignment problem

wrapper<int> i(3);
```

However, the destructors for `int`s and pointers are utterly trivial: they don't do anything, and there is no place you can go to see the definition of the destructor, because the definition doesn't exist. So it's also reasonable to say that they don't have destructors.

Either way, when a pointer goes out of scope it simply disappears; no special code runs.